# Variables not updating in periodic tasks

Tags: python, celery

I have got a django model in which I store minute and hour

```
#models.py
HOUR_CHOICES=(
        ('12', '12PM'),
        ('13', '1PM'),
        ('14', '2PM'),
        ('15', '3PM'),
        ('16','4PM'),
        ('17','5PM'),
        ('18','6PM')
                )
class time(models.Model):
        hour = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=HOUR_CHOICES)
        minute=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS)
```

```
#tasks.py
Value=time.objects.all()
for obj in Value:
                minute=obj.minute
                hour=obj.hour

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=minute, hour=hour), name="newtask")
def newtask():
        f = open("test.txt", "a")
        f.write("test\n")
        f.close()
```

It works fine but when I change hour and minute in my model in doesn't reflect in my tasks that is if initially hour is 1PM and minute=30 then the task will execute at 13:30 but if I change the time to 1PM and minute to 40 then the task is not executed at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you are changing your hour and minute values, the task will not get re-registered. For your case, using ***django-celery-beat*** (https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) seems ideal. Install it with the following command -

```
pip install django-celery-beat
```

then include it in your installed apps -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_celery_beat',
]
```

migrate -

```
python manage.py migrate
```

update your celery settings to include the following -

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = "django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"
```

now suppose your task is defined as -

```
#tasks.py
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def newtask():
        f = open("test.txt", "a")
        f.write("test\n")
        f.close()
```

In you Django admin panel you should now have a registered model called **'Periodic Tasks'**. You can add instances **Periodic Tasks** to run your **newtask** with defined crontabs.

You will need to run celery beat with your worker with some command like this (provide your app name in place of 'app') -

```
celery -A app worker -B -l INFO
```

This could be helpful in getting started with celery beat - https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/django-celery-beat/

Comment: Hi,I have done it and it works fine when I schedule a task in admin panel but when I update the crontab i get this error "Cannot operate on a closed database"

Comment: This seems like an issue with database connection instead of celery now. Somehow your connection is getting closed.